# Get sorted in specific value

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting, tf-idf

I have a list that contains text and its TFIDF score:

```
[['penguji', 117    0.594552 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['saat', 126    0.263102 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['melakukan', 92    0.223703 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['ini', 60    0.772189 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['kebenaran', 73    0.318094 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['selain', 136    0.234254 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['khusus', 76    0.553491 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['dan', 31    0.782068 Name: rank, dtype: float64],...]
```

then I want to sort the score, So I coded this:

```
TFIDF_Score.sort()
print('Sorted list:', TFIDF_Score)
```

The result is the text being sorted, when in fact, the expected output is the score being sorted, like this:

```
[['dan', 31    0.782068 Name: rank, dtype: float64],
 ['ini', 60    0.772189 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['penguji', 117    0.594552 Name: rank, dtype: float64],
 ['khusus', 76    0.553491 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['kebenaran', 73    0.318094 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['saat', 126    0.263102 Name: rank, dtype: float64],
 ['selain', 136    0.234254 Name: rank, dtype: float64], 
 ['melakukan', 92    0.223703 Name: rank, dtype: float64],...]
```

How do I do with the looping? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that second element is `pandas.Series`, use `sorted` with `key`:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [['aaa', pd.Series([0.2])],
     ['bbb', pd.Series([0.1])]]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1].values, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[['aaa', 0    0.2  dtype: float64], 
 ['bbb', 0    0.1  dtype: float64]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sorted`:

```
print(sorted(TFIDF_Score, key=lambda x: -x[2]))
```